# measure 4-20 mA and also power from loop powered

Tags: current-measurement, low-power, instrumentation, 4-20ma

we know to give a command to an actuator in instrumentation we use 4-20 mA loop power. for reading this 4-20 mA I used the circuit below.so the problem is if my circuit only consumes 3mA, how should the current source deliver more current (for example 16mA) to my circuit for commanding? in the other word how should I fix my circuit that can receive 4-20 mA?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj4rtH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

after some searching, I found if I add a zenner diode before my load( in this circuit before my regulator), like the image below

[image]

then because the diode has an I-V characteristics curve below

[image]

then the diode will consume the extra current, but the point that should I consider is
Is=(VS-Vz)/Rs should be greater than 20 mA, so Iz=Is-Iload, because Iload consumes maximum 3mA, the extra current will be consumed with zener diode.
so the final circuit is below:

[image]

Comment: why are you using U1?

Comment: my other side of circuit like LCD,ADC, microcontroller and something else ...

Comment: So how the positioners work in instrumentation? It is power from the 4-20 mA line.

Comment: Usually not. There is a 24 V power supply at the actuator. Questions for you to answer: Q1. How much power does your actuator require at 100% (20 mA)? Q2. What voltage would you require if you tried to power this with 20 mA? (\$ V = \frac {P}{I} \$). Q3: What is the actuator? Have you got a part number and link to a datasheet? Please put all the information in the question and not in the comments.

Comment: your circuit shows the power supply for the circuit .... loop the 4-20 mA line through your circuit before connecting to the input of the regulator .... basically, read the data from the loop before the regulator

Comment: easiest way is a moving coil milliammeter, just connect it in series.

Comment: @Jasen: I was thinking along the same lines in that the actuator might work linearly with 4 to 20 mA. OP doesn't want to share that information for some reason. (In the deleted "answer" s/he says "*the type of actuator is not important in this answer*" but doesn't explain why. For a loop powered actuator I would think it critical to have that information.

Comment: I get the feeling that this has been asked before I remember writing about current-fed buck converters